# Why indexed sequence is faster than linear index in Scala?

Tags: scala, sequence

There are two types of sequences in Scala ( it can be made more general; not specific to Scala ).

```
1. Linear Sequence, where random access of elements involves traversal from one end to the element which is a slower process.
2. Indexed Sequence, where random access of elements is really quick.
```

I would like to know why accessing elements in Indexed sequence is faster ?

Is it because, usage of pointer in their underlying implementation ? (address is calculated by: base address + (size of element * index of the element to retrieve) )

If this is true, why can't the linear sequence be implemented in the same way ? and could have been made faster.

Answer (score 4):

From the [ScalaDocs page](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html): "Vectors are implemented by radix-balanced finger trees of width 32." An `Array` is indexed via address arithmetic, as you've described. Both offer very fast random access (read "indexing") retrieval.

A `List`, on the other hand, does a slow linear lookup for every indexed access. So why are lists so prevalent in Scala code?

It's because random access isn't the only way to access collection elements. If you want to simply traverse the sequence, for example, then a `List` is very efficient.

I read somewhere that Martin Odersky once ran an experiment where he replaced every `List` in the compiler code with `Vector`. The result was a slower compiler.

Answer (score 3):

> If this is true, why can't the linear sequence be implemented in the same way ? and could have been made faster.

Because then it wouldn't be a linear sequence anymore, it would be a random access indexed sequence.

There are some important differences in the memory requirements: an array requires a single, flat, contiguous chunk of memory. E.g. if you want to store 4 billion SHA-1 hashes in an array, you need a huge, single, flat, contiguous, unused chunk of 128 Gioctets. Whereas with a singly-linked list, you would need 4 billion small chunks of 40 octets. That's much easier to find, even though it uses more memory in total (160 Gioctets instead of 128 Gioctets, i.e. 25% more) because of the `next` pointer you have to keep.